# Refresh or relayout the new convertView like first time when listview call getView()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, convertview

I have a listview that use a GestureDetector to handle swipe left.
For each item, layout like below:

```
[FrameLayout]
    [LinearLayout] hidden_menu [/LinearLayout]
    [LinearLayout] main_layout [/LinearLayout]
[/FrameLayout]
```

, it will handle onTouchListener. When I move the main_layout to right, the hidden_menu will be shown [[sample image]](https://www.google.com.vn/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CAcQjRw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdharanikumar%2FIOS_7-SwipeGesture-Android&ei=yxUcVdmLEI2A8QWMmIGQBQ&bvm=bv.89744112,d.dGc&psig=AFQjCNHefCDTEk6Pi01BiyJ3igR7csx9Qg&ust=1427990337118526). When move other item to right, or moveUP or moveDOWN listview, I will hide the hidden_menu of the old (or opened) item using ObjectAnimator (x) and at the end Animation I called the main_layout.invalidate().

My problem is when scroll listview, it will reuse the row layout with ViewHolder pattern, so the new row is wrong layout (some hidden_layout is visibled).

1) Any ideas to refresh the new item when getView() is called?

2) Or how to refresh the animated item like the first time

I hope you guys can understand me !

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in my case:

```
if(holder.mHiddenMenu.getLeft() != 0) {
    holder.mHiddenMenu.setTranslationX(0);
}
```